# ADF create form with combo box

Tags: customization, user-input, oracle-adf, lov

I'm starting with **Oracle ADF and JDeveloper**. I'm doing some basic tutorials first.

From the HR database schema, I'm trying this exercise: create a new location, but in CountryId attribute, show all countries list.

This is more user-friendly, so the user can select Italy instead of typing IT .

For this, I'm doing this steps:

In *Locations* view , choose *CountryId* attribute and create a LOV. This one must read from *CountriesView1*, with value *CountryId* attribute, and show *CountryName* attribute.

1. Drop *LocationsView1* in a page and select ADF Form.
2. Select *CountryId* as a combo box.
3. Drop *Create* operation from *LocationsView1* as a button.
4. Drop *Commit* operation as a button.

When running this page, I see all country names, but when I choose one of them, it does not show me it as selected, and, when commit the new data, CountryId is inserting with null value.

Obviously, I'm doing something in a wrong way. **How can I do this simple form, with CountryId as a list?**

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance. Best regards

***EDIT***: code of *dataEntry.jspx*

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <f:view>
    <af:document id="d1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.d1}">
      <af:messages binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.m1}" id="m1"/>
      <af:form id="f1" binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.f1}">
        <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1"
                               binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.psl1}">
          <f:facet name="center">
            <af:panelFormLayout binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.pfl1}"
                                id="pfl1">
              <af:panelFormLayout binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.pfl2}"
                                  id="pfl2">
                <af:inputText value="#{bindings.LocationId.inputValue}"
                              label="#{bindings.LocationId.hints.label}"
                              required="#{bindings.LocationId.hints.mandatory}"
                              columns="#{bindings.LocationId.hints.displayWidth}"
                              maximumLength="#{bindings.LocationId.hints.precision}"
                              shortDesc="#{bindings.LocationId.hints.tooltip}"
                              binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.it1}"
                              id="it1">
                  <f:validator binding="#{bindings.LocationId.validator}"/>
                  <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false"
                                    pattern="#{bindings.LocationId.format}"/>
                </af:inputText>
                <af:inputText value="#{bindings.StreetAddress.inputValue}"
                              label="#{bindings.StreetAddress.hints.label}"
                              required="#{bindings.StreetAddress.hints.mandatory}"
                              columns="#{bindings.StreetAddress.hints.displayWidth}"
                              maximumLength="#{bindings.StreetAddress.hints.precision}"
                              shortDesc="#{bindings.StreetAddress.hints.tooltip}"
                              binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.it2}"
                              id="it2">
                  <f:validator binding="#{bindings.StreetAddress.validator}"/>
                </af:inputText>
                <af:inputText value="#{bindings.PostalCode.inputValue}"
                              label="#{bindings.PostalCode.hints.label}"
                              required="#{bindings.PostalCode.hints.mandatory}"
                              columns="#{bindings.PostalCode.hints.displayWidth}"
                              maximumLength="#{bindings.PostalCode.hints.precision}"
                              shortDesc="#{bindings.PostalCode.hints.tooltip}"
                              binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.it3}"
                              id="it3">
                  <f:validator binding="#{bindings.PostalCode.validator}"/>
                </af:inputText>
                <af:inputText value="#{bindings.City.inputValue}"
                              label="#{bindings.City.hints.label}"
                              required="#{bindings.City.hints.mandatory}"
                              columns="#{bindings.City.hints.displayWidth}"
                              maximumLength="#{bindings.City.hints.precision}"
                              shortDesc="#{bindings.City.hints.tooltip}"
                              binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.it4}"
                              id="it4">
                  <f:validator binding="#{bindings.City.validator}"/>
                </af:inputText>
                <af:inputText value="#{bindings.StateProvince.inputValue}"
                              label="#{bindings.StateProvince.hints.label}"
                              required="#{bindings.StateProvince.hints.mandatory}"
                              columns="#{bindings.StateProvince.hints.displayWidth}"
                              maximumLength="#{bindings.StateProvince.hints.precision}"
                              shortDesc="#{bindings.StateProvince.hints.tooltip}"
                              binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.it5}"
                              id="it5">
                  <f:validator binding="#{bindings.StateProvince.validator}"/>
                </af:inputText>
                <af:inputListOfValues id="countryIdId"
                                      popupTitle="Search and Select: #{bindings.CountryId.hints.label}"
                                      value="#{bindings.CountryId.inputValue}"
                                      label="#{bindings.CountryId.hints.label}"
                                      model="#{bindings.CountryId.listOfValuesModel}"
                                      required="#{bindings.CountryId.hints.mandatory}"
                                      columns="#{bindings.CountryId.hints.displayWidth}"
                                      shortDesc="#{bindings.CountryId.hints.tooltip}"
                                      binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.countryIdId}">
                  <f:validator binding="#{bindings.CountryId.validator}"/>
                </af:inputListOfValues>
                <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.Create.execute}"
                                  text="Create"
                                  disabled="#{!bindings.Create.enabled}"
                                  binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.cb1}"
                                  id="cb1"/>
                <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.Commit.execute}"
                                  text="Commit"
                                  disabled="#{!bindings.Commit.enabled}"
                                  binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_dataEntry.cb2}"
                                  id="cb2"/>
              </af:panelFormLayout>
            </af:panelFormLayout>
            <!-- id="af_one_column_stretched"   -->
          </f:facet>
        </af:panelStretchLayout>
      </af:form>
    </af:document>
  </f:view>
  <!--oracle-jdev-comment:auto-binding-backing-bean-name:backing_dataEntry-->
</jsp:root>
```

Comment: Can you please show the code for the JSP which has the combo box and the buttons?

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla, thanks for your interest. Finally I have solved my question and I'm writing the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it! 
The steps are:

1. Drop *LocationsView1* in a page and select *ADF Form...*
2. Drop *Create* operation from LocationsView1 as a button.
3. Drop *Commit* operation as a button
4. Remove *CountryId* input text
5. (*Re*)Drop *CountryId* from *LocationsView1*. When JDeveloper asks, choose *Select One
   Choice...*
6. In Bindings section, select *CountryId* and edit (pen icon)
7. Choose *Dynamic List*  radio button and *CountriesView1* in
   ListDataSource combo
8. Match *CountryId* from Data Value with *CountryId* List attribute. Select *CountryName* in the below section.

Well, finally, all countries from COUNTRIES table are listed, and data are inserted into LOCATIONS table.

I hope this will be useful.
Regards